# How to get information from a url

Tags: php, linkedin-api, telegram

Is there a way to get link information through a link (title, subtitle, detail, pictures)?

Like the telegram and LinkedIn in telegram or LinkedIn when you put some link for posting or sending to channel or group you can see some detail of that link.

How can I do this for php code?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add more information about the workflow you want to add this feature to. Do you have a website where people submit links? What tech stack is that site using? Is the link mixed in with text, or separate? What range of sites do you want to present summaries for?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get information about that link is to crawl the page and then extract the data from special meta tags (`<meta property="og:..."`) in the header, then display it accordingly.  Perhaps you need a ready-made package that can do this, or even with jQuery you should be able to parse it.  Below is the example of the tages generated on the current page:

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146161/ability-to-get-article-link-information/58146431">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Stack Overflow">
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com">
    <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Ability to get article link information">
    <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="The only way to get information about that link is to crawl the page and then extract the data from special meta tags (&amp;lt;meta property=&quot;og:...&quot;) in the header, then display it accordingly.  Perha...">

    <meta name="twitter:app:country" content="US">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="Stack Exchange iOS">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="871299723">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146161/ability-to-get-article-link-information/58146431">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="Stack Exchange iOS">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="871299723">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="se-zaphod://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146161/ability-to-get-article-link-information/58146431">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="Stack Exchange Android">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146161/ability-to-get-article-link-information/58146431">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.stackexchange.marvin">
```